# Set unique key in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently using the following code. I'm basically using the example from the mongoose documentation but I'm trying to get the name field to be unique

here I am intentionally creating two unique "kittens" and trying to save both of them

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/test", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true
});

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", function () {
  console.log("Connected to database");
});

const kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, unique: true },
});

kittySchema.methods.speak = function () {
  const greeting = this.name
    ? "Meow name is " + this.name
    : "I don't have a name";
  console.log(greeting);
};

const Kitten = mongoose.model("Kitten", kittySchema);

const fluffy = new Kitten({ name: "fluffy" });
fluffy.save();

const fluffy2 = new Kitten({ name: "fluffy" });
fluffy2.save();
```

Using the unique property doesn't seem to work because I keep getting duplicate entries in the database. I've also tried using the removedups key in the schema which I believe has been deprecated.

Comment: Do you have duplicate entries in your collection already?

Comment: I deleted the collection before running the program, but yes there originally were duplicate entries in the collection. I believe if I change the collection name to something new it also refuses to enforce unique fields

Answer (score 0):

This property unique is not for data to be saved uniquely. It's for unique indexing that will be applied on field.

You can chech documentation here.

https://joshtronic.com/2018/06/07/unique-indexes-with-mongodb-and-mongoose/